# Swift - how to model a complex string?

Tags: swift, string

I have a quite complex string that looks something like:

```
{infobox Country
|country = France
|map = <map lat='47' lng='1.5' zoom='5' view='0' height='320' country='France'/>
|language = French (regional languages: Alsatian, Occitan, Breton, Corsican, Basque, Catalan, ...)
|capital = [[Paris]]
|pop = 65,8 million
|currency = Euro (€)
|hitch = <rating country='fr' />
|BW = FR
}
```

What I want to do is to extract the data, ideally the format of a dictionary where let's say "country" is a key and "France" is a value. The same way for any other key.

How can I approach this? The only idea I have is to do it by using some string slicing and playing with indexes, but it feels like a terrible approach. There has to be some better way of doing this. Is there some way that I can model this the way json file can be done?

Comment: is this a format description or an example of real data? Seems more like a format description.

Comment: It's a downloaded website (provided by the owners) as an XML file. I convert it to a JSON file to be able to easily model it and I get this format as a String. Even the original XML file has this whole instance stored as <text></text>.

Comment: So you have a XML, which has a Text property, where it's a mix between languages and there is also XML inside that Text. So XML within XML, but withouth respecting previous XML for each sub property?  When you say "provided by the owners" Are you saying that you are in contact with them? If yes, they should format the answer, and not put it as text.

Comment: I guess that would be correct. It looks like it's XML inside an XML, but stored as a text. By "provided by owners" I mean it's an open-source website (Wiki-style) and they provide on their website a downloadable version of it in XML format. Unfortunately, I have to work with what I have :(

Comment: Are the spaces around = part of the string or added for readability ?

Comment: Part of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first split it on the "|" and then create key/value pairs using the first "=" as delimiter

```
//Drop the surrounding {} and split the text on |
let rows = input.dropFirst().dropLast().split(separator: "|")
```

Special case for the first element "infobox..."

```
let title = rows.first
```

Then use `reduce` to create the dictionary

```
let dictionary = rows.dropFirst().reduce(into: [String:String]()) {
    guard let index = $1.firstIndex(of: "=") else { return }
    let key = String($1[$1.startIndex..<index]).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    let value = String($1[$1.index(after: index)..<$1.endIndex]).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    $0[key] = value
}

print(title ?? "")
print(dictionary)
```

> infobox Country
> ["capital": "[[Paris]]", "language": "French (regional languages: Alsatian, Occitan, Breton, Corsican, Basque, Catalan, ...)", "map": "<map lat='47' lng='1.5' zoom='5' view='0' height='320' country='France'/>", "BW": "FR", "pop": "65,8 million", "country": "France", "currency": "Euro (€)", "hitch": "<rating country='fr' />"]

Comment: Perfect! It works. Thank you! Now I have to understand how exactly have you done this because it's not very obvious to me on first look :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is structured text, with a formal definition of what it means, then what you're looking at is a *language*, and it's just a case of writing a *parser* for that language. A parser being a function that can convert the input string into a T or describe the error(s). There are lots of different ways to write parsers, (mapping from strings to other data types is extremely common) but perhaps the best one is *parser combinators*, a topic that has been covered by both objc.io and pointfree.co